# Installing matplotlib on Ubuntu 14.04 after installing Python 3 with pyenv

Tags: 14.04, apt, python

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7.6. I have installed `matplotlib` for Python 2. Now, I just installed Python 3.4.2 using `pyenv install 3.4.2`. I then ran `pip install matplotlib` to install `matplotlib` for Python 3. I later discovered the package `python3-matplotlib` for Ubuntu 14.04. I wonder: should I have used `sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib` instead? What is the preferred way of installing `matplotlib` for Python 3 side-by- side with the Python 2 `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I dont have Ubuntu system right now with me. but still I can help you I think.

open your terminal and type as

```
apt-cache search python3-matplotlib
```

If you find it like its available then you can install it from

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

that is the most preferred way.

Now how to use matplotlib with python 3. I have posted a question also in here about how to use python2 and python3 side by side.

Simple , use `python3 <filename.py>` while executing your program with python3-matplotlib

and similarly if you  use python2 then it will load python 2.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, the package is available. Should I try uninstall the `pip` installation, that is: `pip uninstall matplotlib`, and then run `sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib`?

Comment: No need, you can continue.

Comment: Regarding how to run it: Or I could run `pyenv global 3.4.2` and then just `python <filename.py>`?

Comment: 1st one is okay but 2nd one you have to use python3 <filename.py> so it load python3 modules

Comment: Ok, I now installed `python3-matplotlib` using `apt-get`. I ran a test plot, and it still works (for both python 2.7.6 and 3.4.2)..

Comment: some libraries may available in both with same behavior but not very time. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

It is a problem with the development files of libgeos. I have the same problem and it was resolved by installing those libraries. Hope it helps.

Comment: Additional information, such as what commands to run in Terminal, or through the GUI, would be very useful for the OP to understand what needs to be done.