# How do I properly install matplotlib?

Tags: python

I installed matplot.lib by using the command  `sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib`.

While running a program written in python it is showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot
```

What is the problem and how do I install matplotlib properly?

I am trying to run a program that calculates refractive index and the link is https://github.com/polyanskiy/refractiveindex.info-scripts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing matplotlib on Ubuntu 14.04 after installing Python 3 with pyenv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537264/installing-matplotlib-on-ubuntu-14-04-after-installing-python-3-with-pyenv)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] question to add a few details for clarification? What's the program? How did you install the Python interpreter in question and the `mathplotlib` module? Thanks.

Comment: i have tried it by the command "sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib". then when i have tried to run the program there is another problem saying

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot

wht is the problem and how to install the matplotlib properly?

Comment: @AtrayeeHazra It depends on how you installed Python. Tell us how you installed Python and what the output of `which python` or `which python3` is.

Comment: @Steve it is python 2.7.12

Comment: »python 2.7.12« is not using 'python3-matplotlib', but `python-matplotlib`. Please install `python-matplotlib` too.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Can you please move that to an answer?

Answer (score 4):

> apt-get install python3-matplotlib ......  it is python 2.7.12 : 
>   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

`python 2.7.12` is not using 'python3-matplotlib', but python-matplotlib.

Please install `python-matplotlib` too

Answer (score 3):

Try installing matplotlib using pip

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

And if pip3 is not installed on your system try installing pip using following command

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
```