# How to get matplotlib.pyplot to work on ubuntu?

Tags: python, software-center, matplotlib

I'm using Ubuntu to run and compile python. When I tried to import matplotlib.pyplot it said it wasn't found. So I installed matplotlib using

```
pip install matplotlib
```

it said it installed but now I am getting the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Mat_To_Py.py", line 4, in
>   
>       import matplotlib. pyplot as plt   File "/home/wincom/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py",
>   line 126, in 
>       from . import cbook ImportError: cannot import name cbook

What should I do to get it to work?

I've looked and see that other people have be getting different error but when I try those, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv/conda environment?

Comment: @xxbidiao I am not I am connecting to a server through PowerShell.

Comment: @xxbidiao I originally wrote my code in Anaconda. Now I'm transferring them to another server that uses Linux. In Anaconda, it runs correctly but in the server, it does not.

Comment: **pip3** install matplotlib? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037410/how-do-i-properly-install-matplotlib